# How to instal libgluezilla for MAC OS X

Tags: macos, mono

I am trying to run a Mono application on the Mac that has an embedded web browser control. The program runs, but now broswser is show and a message is output:

libgluezilla not found. To have webbrowser support, you need libgluezilla installed

I have searched, but have no idea how to install this. Your guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the embedded web browser control on Mac.  Hence, there is no libgluezilla for Mac.

Answer (score 1):

It worked in 2.4.2 of mono, but not with the latest patch. ( 2.4.2.1 )

I am loosing patience with mono on mac platforms. Things used to work and then stop working, creating a bugzilla entry gets no responses at times.