# Displaying HTML with Mono on Mac OS X

Tags: c#, macos, mono

I gather from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468906/how-to-instal-libgluezilla-for-mac-os-x) and others like it, as well as a thorough web search, that libgluezilla is not available for OS X so it is not possible to use the WebBrowser control.

If that is still the case, is there any other way of displaying HTML within a mono application on a Mac?

EDIT: I have tried open-webkit-sharp but get a run time error like 'cannot find file ......\English.ini', which is odd as it exists in the place that is being searched. Following Lex Li's suggestion I tried with MonoMac, but evidently I need to do more than add in some name spaces and a couple of lines of initialisation code to get the program working as it compiles okay but does not actually open a window when run. I think that MonoMac is probably not the way I want to go anyway as it will prevent the code from being cross platform which is why I am going down the mono route.

Comment: @IanNorton, I could not get hold of webkit-sharp but happened across open-webkit-sharp which looks promising, so thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: If you are using MonoMac, WebKit class is already part of this framework, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104529/mono-use-webkit-with-gtk

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented in my application displaying HTML using mono. I use monobjc(http://www.monobjc.net/) and mono 2.8.10. Monobjc 4.0 has webkit dlls in it. You can use it.

There are two ways -

1. Recommended approach - Using Webkit - Examples available on monobjc site - http://www.monobjc.net/index.php?page=simplewebbrowser. If you download the project you will see the sample code.

Documentation at the site is self explanatory.

2 Not recommended  - Using textView -SubClass NSTextView and hook it up with your project. Now add the following code to the Setter of your subclass . I am pasting the code that can be used with monobjc.

```
 NSString str = new NSString(value);

 NSData data = str.DataUsingEncoding(NSStringEncoding.NSUnicodeStringEncoding);

var attributedString1 = new NSMutableAttributedString();

NSDictionary dict;
```

_htmlString = attributedString1.InitWithHTMLDocumentAttributes(data, out dict).CastAs();

TextStorage.SetAttributedString(_htmlString);